# Having issues generating non-used words for my hang man game

Tags: java

```
 public static String RandomWord() throws IOException {     
            FileReader fr = new FileReader ("./Hang Man File/Words.txt");           
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);                             
            int random = 0;
            String secretWord =" ";
            do {
                random =(int) ((int) 1+(Math.random()*6));
                for (int lineNo = 1; lineNo < 10; lineNo++) {
                    if (lineNo == random) {
                         secretWord = br.readLine();
                    } 
                    else {
                        br.readLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            while(usedWord.contains(secretWord) || secretWord==null); 
            
            usedWord.add(secretWord);
            return secretWord;
        }
```

I am creating a hangman game for my school summative. However I have been experiencing some difficulties with one of my methods called Random Words which performs a few tasks for my program including:
- Generates a random word from a file which contains 6 different words
- **Does not generate the same random word twice**. (this is part I'm having difficulties with).

This program works fine however it randomly stops in the middle returning secretWord as null even when there are still words left in my Words file.

Can anyone please help me please and thank you.

ps: A lot of people asked me why I have `|| secretWord==null` in my do while statement and the reason I have that is because my program was giving me a null exception error and this prevents this from happening.

Comment: This looks like a basic programming problem, your algorithm (desired input and output) is a bit unclear... Could you perhaps describe the program in pseudocode instead, so that people can help you to encode it into java safely?

Comment: Why do you read 10 lines when there are only 6 lines in your file? Look at the java doc for BufferedReader.readLine() and you'll understand why you are getting null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code a bit, it should work, please check.

```
public static String RandomWord() throws IOException {     
    FileReader fr = new FileReader ("./Hang Man File/Words.txt");           
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);                             
    int random = 0;
    String secretWord =" ";
    List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String word= "";
    //Get all the words from the file and put it in a list
    do {
        word = br.readLine();
        if(word != null) {
            wordsList.add(word);
        }
    } while(word != null);
    
    do {
        random =(int) ((int) 1+(Math.random()*6));
        secretWord = wordsList.get(random-1); //Get the word from the list by using index
    }
    while(usedWord.contains(secretWord)); 
    
    usedWord.add(secretWord);
    return secretWord;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pale, I have been struggling a lot with this issue and you instantly just fixed it thank you. ps one day I wish I can be such a good coder as you !

Comment: Glad to be of help :)